# How to solve Self Closing Tag Issue Xml Java

Tags: java, xml-parsing

How to track self closing xml tag?
I want all elements map as key-value pair inside xpath="/response/data" but inside data there is one self closing tag that returns the result as null.
How can I approach the solution? Currently the output is InvalidXml and Null PointerException

My code is blindly assuming that value is there. First, it's blindly assuming that there is an element. Second, it's blindly assuming that there is a single text node as child of such some element. Both are assumptions, and should be checked. Well, if you want a meaningful error message when XML isn't conforming assumptions. In the places item(0), need to verify that the NodeList length is 1, because item() returns null if index is invalid, causing NullPointerException.

```
    String xmlResultPath = "/response/result";
    String xpath = "/response/data";
    String resultDataXml = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><response>    <api>getDocument</api><result>OK</result><data><document did="99999"><value someid="12345" code="123">あり</value><value ditemid="67890" code="234">54014</value><attachfile/></document></data><startTime>2020-11-12 13:25:32.074</startTime><executionTime unit="ms">30</executionTime></response>";
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> nodeValueMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    try
    {
        XMLReader parser = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
        parser.setContentHandler(new DefaultHandler());
        InputSource source = new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(resultDataXml.getBytes()));
        parser.parse(source);

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(resultDataXml)));

        XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();

        XPathExpression exprResultPath = xpath.compile(xmlResultPath);
        String responseResult = exprResultPath.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.STRING).toString();
        if (responseResult.equals("NG")) {
            return null;
        } else if (responseResult.equals("OK")) {

            XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(xpathUrl);
            Object result = expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                parseXMLgetNodeValue(nodeValueMap, nodes.item(i));
            }
        }
    }catch(
    Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("InvalidXml" + e.toString());
        return null;
    }return nodeValueMap;
}

private static LinkedHashSet<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> parseXMLgetNodeValue(
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> nodeValueMap, Node node) {

    Node parent = getParentOfNode(node);
    LinkedHashSet<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> nodeValueMapList = new LinkedHashSet<LinkedHashMap<String, String>>();
    String nodeName = null;
    String nodeValue = null;

    if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
        System.out.println("node.hasChildNodes(): "+ node.hasChildNodes());
        nodeName = node.getNodeName();
        System.out.println("nodeName: "+nodeName);
        NodeList childrens = node.getChildNodes();
        System.out.println("childerens: "+ childrens);
        for (int i = 0; i < childrens.getLength(); i++) {
            parseXMLgetNodeValue(nodeValueMap, childrens.item(i));
        }
    } else {
        nodeValue = node.getNodeValue().trim();
        System.out.println("nodeValue: "+ nodeValue);
        if (nodeValue.length() > 0) {
            nodeName = parent.getNodeName();
            System.out.println("nodeName: "+ nodeName);
            nodeValueMap.put(nodeName, nodeValue);
            nodeValueMapList.add(nodeValueMap);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(nodeValueMapList);
    return nodeValueMapList;
}

private static Node getParentOfNode(Node node) {
    Node parent = node.getParentNode();
    if (parent == null && (Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE == node.getNodeType()))
        parent = ((Attr) node).getOwnerElement();
        System.out.println("parent: "+parent);
    return parent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying trimming non-textual node's Type.
So it works now:

public class Abc {

```
private static void parseXMLgetNodeValue(LinkedHashMap<String, String> nodeValueMap, Node node) {

    Node parent = getParentOfNode(node);
    LinkedHashSet<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> nodeValueMapList = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    String nodeName;
    String nodeValue;

    if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
        System.out.println("node.hasChildNodes(): " + node.hasChildNodes());
        nodeName = node.getNodeName();
        System.out.println("nodeName: " + nodeName);
        NodeList childrens = node.getChildNodes();
        System.out.println("childerens: " + childrens);
        for (int i = 0;
             i < childrens.getLength();
             i++) {
            parseXMLgetNodeValue(nodeValueMap, childrens.item(i));
        }
    } else {

        nodeValue = node.getNodeValue();
        if (nodeValue != null) { // else nothing to do! Is not a text typ!
            nodeValue = nodeValue.trim();
            System.out.println("nodeValue: " + nodeValue);
            if (nodeValue.length() > 0) {
                nodeName = parent.getNodeName();
                System.out.println("nodeName: " + nodeName);
                nodeValueMap.put(nodeName, nodeValue);
                nodeValueMapList.add(nodeValueMap);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(nodeValueMapList);
}



private static Node getParentOfNode(Node node) {

    Node parent = node.getParentNode();
    if (parent == null && (Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE == node.getNodeType())) {
        parent = ((Attr) node).getOwnerElement();
    }
    System.out.println("parent: " + parent);
    return parent;
}



public static void main(String... args) {

    String xmlResultPath = "/response/result";
    String xpath = "/response/data";
    String resultDataXml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" + "<response>\n" + "    <api>getDocument</api>\n" + "    <result>OK</result>\n" + "    <data>\n" + "        <document did=\"99999\">\n" + "            <value someid=\"12345\" code=\"123\">YESS!</value>\n" + "            <value ditemid=\"67890\" code=\"234\">54014</value>\n" + "            <attachfile/>\n" + "        </document>\n" + "    </data>\n" + "    <startTime>2020-11-12 13:25:32.074</startTime>\n" + "    <executionTime unit=\"ms\">30</executionTime>\n" + "</response>";
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> nodeValueMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    try {
        XMLReader parser = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
        parser.setContentHandler(new DefaultHandler());
        InputSource source = new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(resultDataXml.getBytes()));
        parser.parse(source);

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(resultDataXml)));

        XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath txpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();

        XPathExpression exprResultPath = txpath.compile(xmlResultPath);
        String responseResult = exprResultPath.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.STRING).toString();
        if (responseResult.equals("NG")) {
            System.out.println("InvalidXml?");
            return;
        } else if (responseResult.equals("OK")) {

            XPathExpression expr = txpath.compile(xpath);
            Object result = expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
            for (int i = 0;
                 i < nodes.getLength();
                 i++) {
                parseXMLgetNodeValue(nodeValueMap, nodes.item(i));
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("InvalidXml " + e);
        return;
    }
    System.out.println(nodeValueMap);
}
```

}